# "Wordpress failure notice" when I click logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to find a solution for this for all day and I can't find.

I am new to programing, but I got as far as writting the code bellow for a modal login/logout for a website:

```
<?php

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
  $ftjs = "
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').addClass('login');
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').attr('data-target', '#login');
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').attr('href', '');
  ";
} else {
  $link = wp_logout_url( home_url() );
  $ftjs = "
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').addClass('login');
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').html('logout');
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').attr('href', '$link');
  $('li#menu-item-113 > a').attr('title', 'Logout');
  ";
}

?>
```

The problem is that when I click logout, it takes me to a "wordpress failure notice", but I want it to go to the homepage.

Any ideas? The website is [brazpay.com](http://brazpay.com)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have to display menu as per login role than you can use this plugin--Nav Menu Roles